# Do you uninstall the Ruby included with Mac OSX before installing RVM + Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I ran into a problem with multiple Rubies on my machine while trying to use RubyGems. "which -a Ruby" revealed multiple Rubies, so i've imploded my RVM and want to cleanly re-install my Ruby / RubyGems / Rails setup.

Do you uninstall the Ruby pre-loaded on Mac OS X before setting up your RVM? Currently "which -a ruby" only returns the /usr/bin ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just leave it. It will be your `system` ruby which means that you can get rvm to use it with `rvm use system`.

This is of course only if your current ruby is working well. If you are installing rvm on top of two conflicted ruby versions I don't think it will play out well. I installed rvm on a clean install of Lion and it works fine.

Comment: Thank-you, this makes sense with my feed back from "which -a" that somehow I had multiple Rubies from within RVM (or multiple RVMs?). Either way, I decided a fresh install would be better. I appreciate your help!